# Eu queria saber como posso resolver o problema de instalar a biblioteca dataprep em python, já que está retorando um erro e não sei o que fazer

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

[image: O erro gerado]

O erro que a imagem retorna

> The conflict is caused by:
> dataprep 0.3.0 depends on bottleneck<2.0 and >=1.3
> dataprep 0.2.15 depends on bottleneck<2.0 and >=1.3
> dataprep 0.2.14 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.13.post2 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.13.post1 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.13 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.12 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.11 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.10 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.9 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.8 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.7 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.6 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.5 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.4 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.3 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.2 depends on pandas<1.1 and >=1.0
> dataprep 0.2.1 depends on scipy<1.4 and >=1.3
> dataprep 0.2.0 depends on scipy<1.4 and >=1.3
> dataprep 0.1.0 depends on scipy<1.4 and >=1.3
>
> To fix this you could try to:
>
> 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
> 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

este é o que o terminal retorna

Comment: Já verificou a versão do módulo *bottleneck* instalado no sistema?

Comment: Como eu consigo verficar isso ??

Comment: tenta `pip list --outdated` para listar os módulos desatualizados do sistema ou `pip show bottleneck` para ver apenas as informações do módulo *bottleneck*.

Comment: Consegui ver todos os pacotes que tenho. O bottleneck não ta instalado ainda e quando eu tento instalar ele sepado dá esse erro ai. Na real que o que nao ta instalando é justamente isso

Comment: Ai tem diferença, e informação é importante . O erro gerado pela tentativa de instalação do [bottleneck](https://pypi.org/project/Bottleneck/) tem de ser diferente da informação de erro gerada pela instalação do *dataprep*.

Comment: Consegui resolver aqui, Obrigado pela atenção @AugustoVasques, era o C++ que estava numa versão muito antiga e a biblioteca usa ele por baixo dos panos kkkkkk

Answer (score -1):

Tenta instalar usando esses comandos que fazem a instalação direta. Eles podem responder de uma outra forma.

```
pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org msedge-selenium-tools dataprep
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tentei instalar usando esse comando que me passou mas retornar o mesmo erro